# how to uncheck a radio button when another is checked with autopostback=false in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void male_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        female.Checked = !male.Checked;
   }
protected void female_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        male.Checked = !female.Checked;
   }
```

When I Check Male radio button, and also check the Female radio button then Male radio buttons doesn't get unchecked. This above code I used for checking only one radio button at a time.
But its not working. And also I want AutoPostBack=false.

Comment: Please format your code blocks as such and provide more detail as to what you're experiencing. Also, the markup would be beneficial.

Comment: you wouldn't do it in C#...  that is a javascript thing, God bless.

Comment: Can you post the markup?

Comment: <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="male" Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="male_CheckedChanged" />
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="female" Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="female_CheckedChanged" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this using Radio Button List control instead of RadioButton control

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RdoSex" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Male" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Female" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

You do not need a post back nor event handler to achieve this

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [GroupName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if you want one **RadiButton** should be active at a time.

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="MaleRadioButton" 
    Text=" Male" GroupName="gender"/>
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="FemaleRadioButton" 
    Text=" Female" GroupName="gender"/>
```

***FYI:*** Do not use server side **CheckedChanged** event just to make other radio button active.